# No me carga la opción de imagen que quiero mostrar en la web

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Elegir una imagen</title>
    <script>
        function mostrarImagenes(){
```

> He intentado que con un innerHTML me muestre mis imagenes, pero no me funciona

```
            // Muestra mi imagen
            document.getElementById("imagen1").innerHTML = "<img src='1.jpg'>"
            document.getElementById("imagen2").innerHTML = "<img src='2.jpg'>"
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="menu" method="get">
```

> Se supone que con la id accedía a mi método document (del script) y a partir de ese método se me mostraría la imagen

```
        <p>Selecciona para ver imagen:</p>

        <!--Opciones con las imágenes-->
        <input type="radio" id="imagen1" name="fruta">
        <label for="imagen1">Plátano</label><br>

        <input type="radio" id="imagen2" name="fruta">
        <label for="imagen2">Cereza</label><br>
        
        <!--Muestra a opción elegida-->
        <input type="button" value="Mostrar" onclick="mostrarImagenes()";>
        
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`innerHtml` se aplica a todos los objetos que pueden contener HTML. Y `<input>` no puede tener HTML.

También me pregunto por qué estás sobrescribiendo el objeto html en lugar de agregarle elementos secundarios?

Una solución que funcionará:

```js
const imagen = document.createElement("IMG");
imagen.src = "https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/773/koldalen-4-1384902.jpg";

document.getElementById("imagen1").appendChild(imagen);

// esto también funciona:
// document.getElementById("imagen1").innerHTML = "<img src='https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/773/koldalen-4-1384902.jpg'>"
```

```html
<div id="imagen1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

1.- Lo que yo te recomendariá es que crees un **contenedor** en donde muestres la vista previa de la imagen seleccionada. Ejemplo:

```
<div id="vista-previa">
    
  </div>
```

2.- Cuando le das click al boton, optienes la opcion seleccionada y de acuerdo a la opcion muestras dentro de ese contenedor tu imagen. Ejemplo:

```
function mostrarImagenes(){

 //ACCEDEMOS A LAS OPCIONES QUE TIENES
let opcion1 = document.querySelector('#imagen1');
let opcion2 = document.querySelector('#imagen2');
   
 // ACCEDEMOS AL CONTENEDOR ANTES CREADO
   
   let vistaPrevia = document.querySelector('#vista-previa');
   
 // VERIFICAMOS QUE OPCION AH SIDO SELECCIONADA Y MOTRAMOS IMAGEN SEGUN SEA EL CASO
   
   if (opcion1.checked){
     vistaPrevia.innerHTML = `<img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcSndAeqYQIkPDCjOMJbkCykd43uO248vCA2IQ&usqp=CAU'>`;
    }else{
      vistaPrevia.innerHTML = `<img src='https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/1391/1391337.png'>`
    }
  

 }
```

3.- Te dejo un ejemplo practico para que puedas ver el funcionamiento.

```js
 function mostrarImagenes(){

 //ACCEDEMOS A LAS OPCIONES QUE TIENES
let opcion1 = document.querySelector('#imagen1');
let opcion2 = document.querySelector('#imagen2');
   
 // ACCEDEMOS AL CONTENEDOR ANTES CREADO
   
   let vistaPrevia = document.querySelector('#vista-previa');
   
 // VERIFICAMOS QUE OPCION AH SIDO SELECCIONADA Y MOTRAMOS IMAGEN SEGUN SEA EL CASO
   
   if (opcion1.checked){
     vistaPrevia.innerHTML = `<img  src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcSndAeqYQIkPDCjOMJbkCykd43uO248vCA2IQ&usqp=CAU'>`;
    }else{
      vistaPrevia.innerHTML = `<img src='https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/1391/1391337.png'>`
    }
  

 }
```

```html
<form name="menu" method="get">
    <p>Selecciona para ver imagen:</p>

        <!--Opciones con las imágenes-->
        <input type="radio" id="imagen1" name="fruta">
        <label for="imagen1">Plátano</label><br>

        <input type="radio" id="imagen2" name="fruta">
        <label for="imagen2">Cereza</label><br>
        
 <!--Muestra a opción elegida-->
 <input type="button" value="Mostrar" onclick="mostrarImagenes()";>
  
  <!--CREAMOS EL CONTENEDOR DONDE SE MOSTRARA LA VISTA PREVIA-->
  <div id="vista-previa">
    
  </div>
        
</form>
```

4.- NOTA: ESTAMOS ULTILIZANDO **TEMPLATE LITERALS** CUANDO MODIFICAMOS EL **HTML INTERNO**  DE NUESTRA VISTA PREVIA. TE DEJO UN ENLACE PARA QUE PROFUNDICES EN EL TEMA:

[Plantillas literales (plantillas de cadenas)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación y el ejemplo, se entiende perfectamente

Comment: Si es la respuesta que buscas, no olvides marcarla como correcta, por si hay otros usuario con la misma duda, sepan que asi se debe de resolver, saludos.